# How do I get this If statement to run once until it comes back round (the condition is constantly true until slide changes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, flickity

I've created a Flickity slider through Jquery and require a little assitance.
I'm using the selectedIndex as a condition to check what slider is visable. See code below:

```
    $carousel.on( 'select.flickity', function() {
    if (flkty.selectedIndex === 0) {
        hideAllText();
        text0.fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

This is saying, when slider 0 (initial slide) fade in var text0.
I want to do this for 6 sliders but as the slide doesn't change until 4 seconds has been the if statement keeps running so it keeps hiding and showing text.

Any ideas how I can make this a one time run until the slide comes round again.

Thanks :)

Comment: You could set an additional boolean (`if(!waiting && flkty.selectedIndex === 0) ...`)

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the answer but I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I'm still new to Jquery/Javascript but have a decent understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should result in the relevant code only being executed once:

```
text0Shown = false;

$carousel.on('select.flickity', function() {
  if (!text0Shown && flkty.selectedIndex === 0) {
    text0Shown = true;
    hideAllText();
    text0.fadeIn('slow');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Worked perfectly!! :)